# How many levels deep can relationships go?

Tags: relationships

Hopefully simple question but does anyone know how many levels deep the new native relationships template tags can go?  The docs show examples going three levels deep but doesnt mention if there is any limit that would prevent you from going four or five levels down?

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#child-entries-showing-games-and-teams-in-a-season

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no limit, or no one has found it yet..;)